# Authenticate users from external site by ajax

Tags: python, django

#### Problem

I need that people from one specific external website can authenticate in my website by sending a Ajax request. After that, they have to be redirected to my website home.

#### What i'm trying

I've created a custom authentication function and configured the CORS headers, so my request is fully working and i can authenticate from the external website.

The problem is: even if i can authenticate and get a OK response, when i redirect the user to my website, he doesn't have a active session.

#### Why?

I'm guessing that Django sets the session information in the browser cookies, and i'm not doing it.

#### My question:

What do i have to do, so i can keep a user authenticated after he authenticates from an external website?

I would appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i got the job done.

I had to use a form submit + redirect, cause i couldn't save the cookies in the right domain with ajax. I used [jQuery.redirect](https://github.com/mgalante/jquery.redirect) plugin so i don't have to create a form in a external website.

I created a custom authentication function and if the user has valid credentials, i redirect him to my home page (that part got the cookies working right).

I also could remove CORS settings, cause form submits aren't blocked in a cross domain request.